# Error when trying navigating to "Page 2" while on "Page 1" after navigating from my default page

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying to make a relatively simple website but when I try to go to "page 2" from "page 1" it shows me this error:

Server Error in '/NameISYS420' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /NameISYS420/**Homework2**/Homework1/DefaultHW1.aspx

I don't know where that Homework2 part is coming from. The page I am on when I clicked the link was Homework2, so I think it is looking in the Homework2 folder for the Homework1 page when it should be looking in the "NameISYS420" folder for the Homework1 folder. 
In my master page I have this entered for when you click on the link:

`<li><a href="Homework1/DefaultHW1.aspx" title="homework_1">Homework1</a></li>`

I don't know what I am doing wrong, and I will be here to answer any questions!
Sorry if there was the wrong place to post

Comment: It sounds like your `DefaultHW1.aspx` is not where you expect it to be. Beyond that, we can't help you much without more details.

Comment: What details do you need?

Comment: Short version: See [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for pointers. Longer version: You should put enough info that we can help you with your question in a meaningful way. As is, it doesn't show us any of the relevant code that may be affecting it, or any information on things you've already tried (and what results you got from those attempts). Without this information, chances of having someone else understand your problem as well as you do and being able to solve it is next to nil.

Comment: Based on your edit - have you done a "View Source" of the page with the link to make sure it indeed matches what you expect to be there? It's possible your project is out of sync with what you're testing.

Comment: When I click "View Source" it pulls up the correct code, but when I hover over the link it shows the '/NameISYS420/Homework2/Homework1/DefaultHW1.aspx' instead of the '/NameISYS420/Homework1/DefaultHW1.aspx' that it should show.
I just don't understand what is going wrong, I've done this plenty of times before and I've never had this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you describe (including the updates in the comments) it sounds like your "main" page is in the `/NameISYS420/Homework2` folder. Your link to `a href="Homework1/DefaultHW1.aspx"` is then resolving to `/NameISYS420/Homework2/Homework1/DefaultHW1.aspx`.

You can solve this by any (not all - just pick the one that is best for you) of the following:

1. Move your main page to the `/NameISYS420` folder
2. Change the link reference to `a href="../Homework1/DefaultHW1.aspx"`
3. Change the link to use an absolute reference instead of a relative reference: `a href="/NameISYS420/Homework1/DefaultHW1.aspx"`

Comment: That is exactly what happened. Thank you so much! I used number 3. Thanks for helping me even though my original question wording was pretty bad!

Comment: No problem. Just remember that more details is generally better, as it will help people actually narrow down your problem and provide a useful answer.